# Bootstrap: Justified shrink the button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a div where I want to use a full-width button group with 3 button.
The 2nd and the 3th button "text" will be only font-awesome icons, so I want them to be smaller than the 1st. (For example 60%-20%-20%)

I tried this snippet (I didn't used the "other two are smaller" style yet, so it have to be a 33%-33%-33% buttongroup)

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <button class="btn btn-default disabled">
        {{$buttonText}}
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

But the whole `btn-group` only occupies the 25% of the div. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use justified button groups with `<button>` elements, you must wrap each button in a button group. See bootstrap documentation here: [With `<button>` elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#with-%3Cbutton%3E-elements)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button class="btn btn-default disabled">
      asdasd
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button class="btn btn-warning">
      <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button class="btn btn-danger">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use grid layout for my rescue. My btn no longer is restricted by width of the content.

```
<div class="row">
<button class="col-xs-10 btn btn-primary">
    BTN 1
</button>
<button class="col-xs-1 btn btn-warning">
    <i class="fa fa-edit"> BTN 2</i>
</button>
<button class="col-xs-1 btn btn-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"> BTN 3</i>
</button>
```